# SQL flat table query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have imported some data from an excel table in to an SQL table and I now need to write a view over the data to combine it with some other fields.

My problem is that the table is in the following form with these columns;

**Name**    **Project_One_ID**    **Project_Two_ID**    **Project_Three_ID**

Rather than the form I could use, which would be a link table with columns like this;

**Name**  **ProjectID**

Is it possible to convert this type of table? Or use it as it is? I could do it in code but im struggling in SQL.  I have two other tables that need to link on to either side of this link table to create my overall view.

Thanks for any pointers,

Comment: If one of the project ID fields is filled are the others null?

Comment: no they can all be full.. or some can be empty.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could do it as a `UNION` and then join to other tables:

```
SELECT * FROM
(
    SELECT Name, Project_One_ID ProjectID
    FROM Projects
    UNION ALL
    SELECT Name, Project_Two_ID ProjectID
    FROM Projects
    UNION ALL
    SELECT Name, Project_Three_ID ProjectID
    FROM Projects
) AS P
INNER JOIN ProjectData PD
ON P.ProjectID = PD.ProjectID
```

Comment: Both this and the answer below (cross apply) worked wonderfully. Are there any benefits with using one over the other?

Answer (score 2):

Depending on your version of SQL Server you can use CROSS APPLY to UNPIVOT the data.

CROSS APPLY and VALUES will work in SQL Server 2008+:

```
select name,
  ProjectId
from yourtable
cross apply
(
  values
  ('Project_One_ID', Project_One_ID),
  ('Project_Two_ID', Project_Two_ID),
  ('Project_Three_ID', Project_Three_ID)
) c (col, ProjectId);
```

If you are using SQL Server 2005, then you can use CROSS APPLY with UNION ALL:

```
select name,
  ProjectId
from yourtable
cross apply
(
  select 'Project_One_ID', Project_One_ID union all
  select 'Project_Two_ID', Project_Two_ID union all
  select 'Project_Three_ID', Project_Three_ID  
) c (col, ProjectId)
```

Answer (score 0):

if name is a foreign key (unusual - but i suppose possible)
then you could union these things together..

```
select name, project_one_id as project_id
from newtable
union
select name, project_two_id 
from newtable
union
select name, project_three_id     
from newtable
```

Comment: Are you sure you don't want to use `UNION ALL`?

Answer (score 0):

The most efficient way to write this query is as an `unpivot`.  This only scans the table once.  Here is an example:

```
with t as (select 'a' as name, 1 as project_one, 2 as project_two, 3 as project_three)
select name, project
from t
unpivot (project for col in (project_one, project_two, project_three)) as unpvt
```

You can put the `unpivot` in a view for easy access or use it to create a new table with the columns you want.